# How to handle form object in array to add list

Tags: reactjs

i have a problem when i create an Array and i put object to array, when i create handleform Function, the field cannot typing, just return null, i dont know why, i follow the intruction from guy on stackoverflow too.

```
this.state = {
            post : [],
            isChecked : false,
            list : [],
            object : {
                email : '',
                password : ''
            }

        }
```

```
handleForm = (e) => {
        let newObject = {...this.state.object};
        newObject[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
        this.setState({
            object : newObject
      })
    }

handleAdd = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            list : [...this.state.list, this.state.object]
        })

 }
```

mycomponent

```
<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                { 
                  list.map(h => (
                    <FormGroup key = "i">
                    <FormGroup >
                      <Label for="email">Email</Label>
                      <Input onChange={handleForm} value={h.email} type="email"  name = "email" className="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="" />
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup >
                      <Label htmlFor="password">Password</Label>
                      <Input onChange={handleForm} value={h.password} type="password"  name = "password" className="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="" />
                    </FormGroup> 
                    </FormGroup>
                ))}                   

                  <FormGroup>
                  <ButtonAntd type="primary" className="text right" onClick={handleAdd}>+</ButtonAntd>{' '}
                  </FormGroup>
                 <FormGroup >
                    <label> 
                        <input type="checkbox" checked={isChecked} onChange = {toggleChange} value="isChecked"/>{' '}
                         Anda yakin, Data anda sudah benar ?
                    </label>
                 </FormGroup>
                      <ButtonAntd type="primary" htmlType="submit" >Submit</ButtonAntd> {' '}
                      <ButtonAntd type="danger" onClick={handleBatal} >Batal</ButtonAntd>
                </Form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing the key factor here handle change applies on the `object` on the state and the forms fields and values coming from the list instead, so to resolve this issue you need to give each of the lists objects an id and then when a change happens you update the matching object with the id and updates it's fields:

```js
import shortid from 'shortid'

// the rest of your code here

handleForm = ({ target: { name, value, id } }) => {
    const newList = list.map(obj => {
        if (obj.id === id)
            return { ...obj, [name]: value }
        return obj
    })
    this.setState({
        list: newList
    })
}

handleAdd = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        list: [
            ...this.state.list,
            {
                ...this.state.object,
                id: shortid.generate()
            }]
    })

}
```

> Note: 
>   you can follow another approach to update the data but needs to make a local state for each new component, However, this should work fine

[demo Script](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-meitner-ts926?fontsize=14)

Comment: i should npm install shordid?

Comment: but is there any way to make this happen without shortid ?

Comment: for the current data structure, it would be challenging to update fields nested on a list, so you have to know where you should change, I would say you can use the map index and it will work but that's wrong and will lead to bigger issues on the future

Comment: i already follow ur instruction, im getting error, cannot read property id, but i already define id in input

Comment: can you explain whats happed, and don't forget to add the `id` form the object to the input filed ,sth like this => <Input ...props id={h.id} />

Comment: i did bro, now cannot read propery email. i already use  value = {h.email}

Comment: on the secend add, first form is succes, the second form , email and password cannot typing

Comment: for the second form, you can extract the data when the form is submitted of you continue and make it controlled component

Comment: ```<Input onChange={handleForm} value={h.email} type="email"  name = "email" id = {h.id} className="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="" />```

Comment: when i use add field again, become error cannot read propery email, i just can type for the first form, second form always fail

Comment: did you debugged your list and looked at the second item on the list ?

Comment: second item, undefined. first item of array index [0] . have field username = "asdasd", password = "asdasda", second item undefined and error cannot read propery email

Comment: that because of the `handleAdd` somehow it's adding `undefined` , pls make sure the `handleAdd` matches the syntax above.

Comment: i copy paste ur code master, but still no change, the first item is succes to create and i console log that, but when go to next array index of 1 . the console.log become undefined

Comment: yes sorry, I just notice the that I was missing the `return obj` after the if statement on the `handleForm` function`

Comment: I have added the scripts on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-meitner-ts926?fontsize=14)

Comment: holy mother, i missing tho, before i return obj but the page is not render yet, so i type input still wrong then i removereturn obj. lol. thank you so much

Comment: bro i have a question about this problem again. how to remove an id after finish fill all the data and want to submit wihtout id ? just email and password

Comment: you can filter them out like => `list.map( ({ id , ...fields }) => fields )` before submitting them

Comment: you save my day brroo, very thankssssss. you helped me alot. can i ask you, how did you learn the react js actually, im new in react js, i try hard to learn this library.

Comment: You are welcome, and I'm glad to hear that , we here to help each other ^_^ .
The most effective way that worked for me, is practicing a lot,& implement any Idea on your mind (and read the [docs](https://reactjs.org/)) ,and remember don't rush to the results just learn and be patient and eventually we will be super ‍♂️.

Comment: many thanks again, i have to try more and more, thanks once again ^.^